# Jquery - Need to Check HTML Table TD is clicked or not

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table like this,

```
<table>
<tr class="AltTR">
<td>
   First TD
</td>
<td>
  Second TD
</td>
<td>
  Third TD
</td>
<td>
  Fourth TD
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When i click a table row, i want to do one operation, example need to show the alert window...

my jquery code is given below,

```
$(function(){
$(".AltTR").click(function() {

         //if ($(this).find("td:first").is(":click"))
    if ($(this).find("td:first").trigger('click'))
                alert("1st TD is clicked");
            else
                alert("Other than 1st TD is clicked");

     });

});
```

How to achieve this?

i have another doubt, "There is one  link tag is in first TD, when we click that link, dont display any alert messages.. otherwise we want to display alert message whether it's first TD or any other TD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the index methord to your `td` since its the `td` where a user is clicking. Also you must wrap your code inside `$(document).ready( function()` like;

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".AltTR td").click(function(){
    if($(this).index() == 0){
        alert("1st TD is clicked");
    }
    else{
        alert("Other than 1st TD is clicked");
    }
  });
});
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/N3dBg/1/)*** is a working Live Demo.

And ***[here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/N3dBg/2/)*** is the updated fiddle as per your requirement.

Comment: i have another doubt, "There is one link tag is in first TD, when we click that link, dont display any alert messages.. otherwise we want to display alert message whether it's first TD or any other TD

Comment: upvote my answer if you found it helpful first. Do you want to disable all alerts when user click the link (means after clicking the link, no alert will be returned if user click any other `td`) or you just want to disable alert for that link only?

Comment: Hi @blasteralfred.. Okay... i tell my actual need, when we click that row, it will display the new row after clicked TR. In first TD have a link, when we click that link its redirect to another page, that time dont need to display that new row....

Comment: I tried with stopPropagation().. But, the new row is displayed before redirect to another page.....

Comment: Hi @blasteralfred.. Please check this link.. http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/ENJBs/27/.... When we click first row, the new row will be diplaying perfectly & also when we click **link** the new row is not displayed.... but when we do the same operation in 2nd row, it's not working....

Comment: can you post this as a question please and let me know by commenting here wen you post? r u online now?

Comment: Even if you are online, you are not posting question means u don't give importance right. Alright then.

Comment: wait... i will ask & let u know, also give me a idea about question _Title_

Comment: Just give a question title "jQuery row re-size disable problem" and post your code in fiddle. Since I answer, don't worry about anything else.

Comment: Check my question..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932486/jquery-stoppropagation-is-not-working-in-table-tr-with-live-event

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `index()` method in jQuery and do this:

```
$(".AltTR td").click(function(){
    if($(this).index() == 0){
        alert("1st <td>");
    }
    else{
        alert("other than 1st <td>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Karl Laurentius Roos.. Thanks for your reply... it's works fine... i have another doubt, "There is one <a> link tag is in first TD, when we click that link, dont display any alert messages.. otherwise we want to display alert message whether it's first TD or anything"

Comment: Seems like you got the answer.

Comment: Hi @Karl Laurentius Roos.. Please check this link.. [Check this link](jsfiddle.net/smanimani/ENJBs/27).... When we click first row, the new row will be diplaying perfectly & also when we click **link** the new row is not displayed.... But when we do the same operation in 2nd row, the new row is displayed when click **link**....

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property of the event object.

e.g.

```
$(".AltTR").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).find("td:first").is(e.target)) {
        // first td clicked
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bt9xX/

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: http://jsfiddle.net/JXLs3/

```
var targetTds = $('.AltTR');
$('td',targetTds).click(function() {
    alert($(this).html());


    if ($(this).is( $(':first',targetTds) )) {
       alert('first');        
    }
    else if ($(this).is( $(':last',targetTds) ) ) { 
       alert('last');                
    }
    else {
        alert('everything else');
    }

});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

​
```