# Jquery - stopPropagation is not working in table tr with live event

Tags: jquery, html

Please check the below JS Fiddle link,

http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/ENJBs/27/

Actually my need is, I have a *link* button in every first TD in all TR row.. When we click a table row, want to display a new row after clicked row, but i dont want to display that new row in link button click...

Check the above link... When we click first row, the new row will be diplaying perfectly & also when we click link button new row is not displayed....
But when we do the same operation in 2nd row, the new row is displayed when click link button....

i dont want to display that new row, when we click *link* button...

How to i solve this?

Comment: Are you aware that [`.live()` is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com)? You should be using `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `event.stopPropagation()` in the event handler with `.live()` method.

> Calling event.stopPropagation() in the event handler is ineffective in
>   stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event has
>   already propagated to document.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `:first` pseudo and use this;

```
$(".AltTR td a").live('click',function(e){
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/ENJBs/28/)*** is a working fiddle.

Comment: Hi @blasteralfred.. Assume, i have a link button in every TD, I want to disable the new row when First TD *link* button click.. How to i achieve it?

Comment: so if first link is clicked, nothing should happen again and no other rows should be expanded right?

Comment: Yes.... dont need to display that new row, just it's redirecting to another page, but its just slide down the new row before redirect to new page

Answer (score 0):

You need to change :first  to :first-child  see docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

Also for jquery 1.7.2 live is deprecated, use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(".AltTR").on('click', 'td', function(e){
    var GetTRId = $(this).closest("tr").attr('id');
    //alert("AltTR");
        expandrow(GetTRId);
});

$(".AltTR").on('click', 'td:first-child a', function(e){
    //alert("a");
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```